# How to get a whole list of compiled files of Linux kernel?

Tags: gcc, compilation, makefile, kernel, source-insight

I'm working on different Android projects and need to setup project in Source Insight for different kernel source tree.
There are many unused files in kernel, I want to find a method to pick out all .c,.h,.S files that are compiled in kernel. I was nearly crazy when I pick the source files manually.

I'd wrote a script that can pick up the files corresponding to the .o files, but there are some .o files are compiled by multiple .c files, which make it more complicated.

Is there an easier way to know what files are handled in the compiling process?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

It's my first question in stackoverflow, I love here so much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I always need to search the kernel source without looking at powerpc, ia86, sparc, alpha, infiniband, etc.  Assuming you can compile the kernel, several ways of doing this:

1) $K/scripts/basic/fixdep.c is called from Makefile.build to create a .cmd file for each source which contains information about the compile options, compile source/target and dependency list.  Modify this to write a separate file with just the source file or source/dependencies.

2) Hack $K/scripts/Makefile.build to log the currently compiled file.  See the cmd_as_o_S and rule_cc_o_c areas.

Option #1 is the best but requires a little coding.  Option #2 is easiest but a true hack, and doesn't pick up the dependencies.