# How to find out list of kernel files compiled by a kernel?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working on project, where only small amount of kernel code {20%}is getting compiled.

I want to know if there is any way to find out what are the files actually compiled in a kernel image.

I found out that for every compiled file there is a  "*.o.cmd" file which contains dependencies also.

Can anyone tell/explain me, how "*.o.cmd" files are getting generated?

I was looking @basic/fixdep.c file but didn't get any success.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can parse the output of `make` command.

Comment: Simple googling shows several links at once: [link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440819/how-to-get-a-whole-list-of-compiled-files-of-linux-kernel), [link #2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191050/find-out-which-kernel-source-files-were-used-when-kernel-was-compiled). Both links suggest working methods, though not completely automatic. Check out also `make COMPILED_SOURCE=1 cscope tags` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676829/vim-configuration-for-linux-kernel-development/33682137)) and "Eclipse CDT for Linux kernel" if you're looking for indexing tools.